Memory management batch file script not working
using the information from this exchange(When Blender crashes during rendering), I made a script that for some reason doesn't work. The script I made is just like the one in the example except for the file paths. Here is the script(I censored out my real name)

C:
cd "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 4.1"
for /l %%i in (700,1,1599) do (
  set 'foo=0000%%i'
  set 'foo=!foo:~-4!'
  if not exist 'C:\tmp!foo!.png' (
    blender.exe -b "C:\Users\#####\Downloads\Blender Projects\Random\Cross.blend" -f %%i
  )
)
ffmpeg -r 30 -start_number 1 -i "C:\tmp\%%04d.png" -f mp4 -crf 15 "C:\tmp\video.mp4"

In the next block, I will provide the output in the terminal. As well as some context before. After running the bat file, a terminal window opens and blender begins to work, it initiates the render if the first frame isn't already rendered and once it is done rendering, it outputs the image and then doesn't do anything else. The same happens if the frame already exists, it recognizes that it already exists, skips that frame, and doesn't render anything else. Here is the output of the terminal when the frame doesn't exist already(again, I censored my name):
Blender 4.1.1 (hash e1743a0317bc built 2024-04-15 23:33:30)
Read prefs: "C:\Users\#####\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\config\userpref.blend"
====================
Bradley's Geo Node Presets
====================
blenderkit addon: Verbose is enabled
blenderkit addon: Read in JSON settings from file
Failed to register scene update handler
'clear' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
importing .addon
importing .ui
importing .simulation
importing .addon
importing .ui
importing .simulation
WARN (bgl): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v410\blender.git\source\blender\python\generic\bgl.cc:2678 BPyInit_bgl: 'bgl' imported without an OpenGL backend. Please update your add-ons to use the 'gpu' module.
Loading SL Preferences...
Error in bpy.app.handlers.load_post[2]:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\#####\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\scripts\addons\atomic_data_manager\ui\missing_file_ui.py", line 175, in autodetect_missing_files
    (missing.images() or missing.libraries()):
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\#####\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\scripts\addons\atomic_data_manager\stats\missing.py", line 70, in libraries
    return get_missing(bpy.data.libraries)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\#####\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\scripts\addons\atomic_data_manager\stats\missing.py", line 45, in get_missing
    if not datablock.packed_files and not os.path.isfile(abspath):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Library' object has no attribute 'packed_files'. Did you mean: 'packed_file'?
0  meshes freed
Read blend: "C:\Users\#####\Downloads\Blender Projects\Random\Cross.blend"
Error in bpy.app.handlers.load_post[2]:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\#####\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\scripts\addons\atomic_data_manager\ui\missing_file_ui.py", line 175, in autodetect_missing_files
    (missing.images() or missing.libraries()):
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\#####\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\scripts\addons\atomic_data_manager\stats\missing.py", line 70, in libraries
    return get_missing(bpy.data.libraries)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\#####\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\scripts\addons\atomic_data_manager\stats\missing.py", line 45, in get_missing
    if not datablock.packed_files and not os.path.isfile(abspath):
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Library' object has no attribute 'packed_files'. Did you mean: 'packed_file'?
0  meshes freed
Error in bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre[15]:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\#####\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\scripts\addons\rbc_addon_pro\__init__.py", line 7441, in frame_change_pre_handler_156BA
    if (bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache.frame_end != bpy.context.scene.frame_end):
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'point_cache'
Error in bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post[7]:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\#####\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\4.1\scripts\addons\rbc_addon_pro\__init__.py", line 2409, in frame_change_post_handler_DD6BD
    if ((bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache.info == bpy.context.scene.sna_rbw_info) and (bpy.context.scene.frame_current != bpy.context.scene.frame_end)):
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'point_cache'
Fra:700 Mem:765.27M (Peak 765.27M) | Time:00:00.27 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Synchronizing object | Sphere
Fra:700 Mem:769.77M (Peak 769.77M) | Time:00:00.27 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Synchronizing object | Plane.001
Fra:700 Mem:765.81M (Peak 769.77M) | Time:00:00.32 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Synchronizing object | GodRay Fog Noise
Fra:700 Mem:765.81M (Peak 769.77M) | Time:00:00.32 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Synchronizing object | Wisp
Fra:700 Mem:765.81M (Peak 769.77M) | Time:00:00.32 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Initializing
Fra:700 Mem:753.08M (Peak 769.77M) | Time:00:00.33 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Waiting for render to start
Fra:700 Mem:753.08M (Peak 769.77M) | Time:00:00.33 | Mem:0.00M, Peak:0.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Loading render kernels (may take a few minutes the first time)
Fra:700 Mem:753.08M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.38 | Mem:0.01M, Peak:0.01M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Scene
Fra:700 Mem:753.08M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.38 | Mem:0.01M, Peak:0.01M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Shaders
Fra:700 Mem:753.18M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.38 | Mem:0.02M, Peak:0.02M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Procedurals
Fra:700 Mem:753.18M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.38 | Mem:0.02M, Peak:0.02M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Background
Fra:700 Mem:753.18M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.38 | Mem:0.02M, Peak:0.02M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Camera
Fra:700 Mem:753.18M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.38 | Mem:0.02M, Peak:0.02M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Meshes Flags
Fra:700 Mem:753.18M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.38 | Mem:0.02M, Peak:0.02M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Objects
Fra:700 Mem:753.18M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.38 | Mem:0.02M, Peak:0.02M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Objects | Copying Transformations to device
Fra:700 Mem:757.91M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.38 | Mem:4.60M, Peak:4.60M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Objects | Applying Static Transformations
Fra:700 Mem:757.91M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.39 | Mem:4.60M, Peak:4.60M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Particle Systems
Fra:700 Mem:757.91M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.39 | Mem:4.60M, Peak:4.60M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Particle Systems | Copying Particles to device
Fra:700 Mem:757.91M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.39 | Mem:4.60M, Peak:4.60M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Meshes
Fra:700 Mem:757.99M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.39 | Mem:4.60M, Peak:4.60M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Mesh | Computing attributes
Fra:700 Mem:759.22M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.39 | Mem:4.60M, Peak:4.60M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Mesh | Copying Attributes to device
Fra:700 Mem:758.00M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.39 | Mem:4.61M, Peak:4.61M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Geometry BVH Cube.024 4/4 | Building BVH
Fra:700 Mem:758.00M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.39 | Mem:4.61M, Peak:4.61M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Geometry BVH Plane.001 2/4 | Building OptiX acceleration structure
Fra:700 Mem:758.00M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.39 | Mem:4.73M, Peak:5.13M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Scene BVH | Building
Fra:700 Mem:758.15M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.39 | Mem:4.73M, Peak:5.13M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Scene BVH | Building OptiX acceleration structure
Fra:700 Mem:758.15M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.41 | Mem:7.86M, Peak:14.98M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Scene BVH | Copying BVH to device
Fra:700 Mem:758.15M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.41 | Mem:7.86M, Peak:14.98M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Mesh | Computing normals
Fra:700 Mem:758.33M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.41 | Mem:7.86M, Peak:14.98M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Mesh | Copying Mesh to device
Fra:700 Mem:758.33M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.41 | Mem:8.04M, Peak:14.98M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Objects Flags
Fra:700 Mem:758.33M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.41 | Mem:8.19M, Peak:14.98M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Primitive Offsets
Fra:700 Mem:758.41M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.41 | Mem:8.27M, Peak:14.98M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Images
Fra:700 Mem:758.41M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.41 | Mem:8.27M, Peak:14.98M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Camera Volume
Fra:700 Mem:758.41M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.41 | Mem:8.27M, Peak:14.98M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Lookup Tables
Fra:700 Mem:758.41M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.41 | Mem:8.35M, Peak:14.98M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Lights
Fra:700 Mem:758.41M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.41 | Mem:8.35M, Peak:14.98M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Lights | Computing distribution
Fra:700 Mem:758.41M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.46 | Mem:8.35M, Peak:14.98M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Lights | Computing tree
Fra:700 Mem:763.90M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.50 | Mem:13.84M, Peak:14.98M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Integrator
Fra:700 Mem:765.90M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.50 | Mem:15.84M, Peak:15.84M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Film
Fra:700 Mem:765.91M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.50 | Mem:15.76M, Peak:15.84M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Lookup Tables
Fra:700 Mem:765.91M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.50 | Mem:15.85M, Peak:15.85M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Baking
Fra:700 Mem:765.91M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.50 | Mem:15.85M, Peak:15.85M | Scene, ViewLayer | Updating Device | Writing constant memory
Fra:700 Mem:770.21M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.52 | Mem:407.85M, Peak:407.85M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 0/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.57 | Remaining:00:00.94 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 1/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.70 | Remaining:00:00.81 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 19/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.85 | Remaining:00:00.66 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 48/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.89 | Remaining:00:00.62 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 64/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.92 | Remaining:00:00.59 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 80/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.95 | Remaining:00:00.56 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 96/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:00.98 | Remaining:00:00.53 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 112/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.01 | Remaining:00:00.50 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 128/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.04 | Remaining:00:00.47 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 144/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.07 | Remaining:00:00.44 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 160/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.09 | Remaining:00:00.42 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 176/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.11 | Remaining:00:00.40 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 192/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.14 | Remaining:00:00.37 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 208/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.16 | Remaining:00:00.35 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 224/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.18 | Remaining:00:00.33 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 240/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.20 | Remaining:00:00.31 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 256/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.22 | Remaining:00:00.29 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 272/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.24 | Remaining:00:00.27 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 288/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.26 | Remaining:00:00.25 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 304/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.28 | Remaining:00:00.23 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 320/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.30 | Remaining:00:00.21 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 336/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.33 | Remaining:00:00.19 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 352/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.34 | Remaining:00:00.17 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 368/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.36 | Remaining:00:00.15 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 384/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.38 | Remaining:00:00.13 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 400/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.40 | Remaining:00:00.11 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 416/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.42 | Remaining:00:00.09 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 432/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.44 | Remaining:00:00.07 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 448/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.46 | Remaining:00:00.05 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 464/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.48 | Remaining:00:00.03 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 480/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.37M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.49 | Remaining:00:00.02 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 496/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.44M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.49 | Remaining:00:00.02 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Sample 0/512
Fra:700 Mem:770.44M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.49 | Remaining:00:00.02 | Mem:408.00M, Peak:408.00M | Scene, ViewLayer | Finished
Fra:700 Mem:752.74M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.54 | Compositing
Fra:700 Mem:752.74M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.54 | Compositing | Determining resolution
Fra:700 Mem:752.74M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.54 | Compositing | Initializing execution
Fra:700 Mem:753.16M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.54 | Compositing | Tile 1-1
Fra:700 Mem:753.10M (Peak 774.47M) | Time:00:01.54 | Compositing | De-initializing execution
Saved: 'C:\tmp\0700.png'
Time: 00:01.59 (Saving: 00:00.05)

blenderkit INFO: Unregistering BlenderKit add-on [19:35:06.103, __init__.py:2432]
Preview Collection already removed
Saving SL Preferences...

If anyone needs more info just let me know, THANK YOU!

I'm not sure exactly what the "!" in the line if not exist 'C:\tmp!foo!.png' ( is used for - but this doesn't look right to me. You want to check if there is a file like C:\tmp\0700.png but actually, I bet it checks for the file C:\tmp0700.png because there is only one backslash. Try this line if not exist 'C:\tmp\!foo!.png' (

Unfortunately this didn't change anything.
